# No derived data for builds after upgrading to Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I have a MacBook Pro that has Mac OS X 10.7.5. I was doing iOS development using Xcode 4.4 and I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.5.

For my application, I have built some 3rd party libraries that it depends on, and those libraries need to be placed in a certain location so my application can pick them up and use them. However I'm unable to locate the recent builds of the libraries because, even though Xcode says the libraries build successfully, nothing is available for derived data in the Organizer.

What can I do to determine where these libraries are being built?

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 4.5 look at Preferences->Locations.

This shows where your Derived Data location actually lives on the File System.

Click on the arrow next to the Derived Data path to show the path in the Finder.

I recently upgraded from Xcode 4.3.3 and found that the build location has been automatically changed to Custom, so my (debug) build products are now in:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug

I am guessing that Apple have made this change to simplify the location of build products in a single location. In Xode 4.3.3 for example build products were placed under:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX

where XXX is a randomly generated folder based on your Xcode project name.

I have also found it useful to enable hidden folders to be displayed in the Finder so that you can actually browse the contents of your Library folder. I used the free Onyx tool to enable the display of hidden folders.

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 3):

I went into Organizer, right clicked on the project which was no longer generating derived data (even though I could see it was... just the delete button was greyed out) and removed it from organizer. When I reopened the project it button was available again